# Python: How to store values of matrix value

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

So I am given a matrix

```
---
-m-
p--
```

where I have to find out what directions m must take to reach p like left,down etc.

```
for i in range(n):
  for j in range(n):
    if grid[i][j] == "m":
        m = [i,j]
    elif grid[i][j] == "p":
        p = [i,j]
```

I am able to find location of m and p but want to compare [i,j] of m and p so that it m can move to p. when I try to compare them or add +1 to i of m I am not able to do it. 
Any particular way I should be storing the location of m and p so that I can work on their values .

Comment: What are you trying that isn't working? What do you think `m` is after the loop runs? What do you think `p` is after the loop runs? Have you printed them to see if they are what you think they are? What should the result of whatever you're trying to do be?

Comment: for instance, after the code above, do `print(p)` and `print(m)` say what they think you should?

Comment: When I print m , I get output [1,1] and for p[2,0] . But I want to add 1 to i value of m and make it [2,1] and then I get error or I try to compare p[i] and q[i]

Comment: What do you mean by moving m to p. Like over writing p with m ?

Comment: If m is `[1,1]`, you can change it to `[2,1]` with `m[0] = m[0] + 1` OR `m[0] += 1`. How are you doing it? How are you comparing them?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting this question, it was a really fun little script to write!

Not perfect, but you can use these functions to do what I dubbed "matrix pathing". Check it out:

```
# Find the position of a character in the matrix (returns tuple)
def matrix_find( matrix, ch ):
    m_len, m_wid = (len(matrix.split('\n')[0]), len(matrix.split('\n')))
    for line_num, line in enumerate(matrix.split('\n')):
        for letter_num, letter in enumerate(line):
            if letter == ch:
                return (line_num + 1, letter_num + 1)

# Find the path from one character's location to another
def matrix_pathing(start, finish):
    if start == finish:
        print("No pathing needed.")
    else:
        print("Move {} {}"*(0 if start[0] == finish[0] else 1)).format(abs(start[0]-finish[0]), "down" if start[0] < finish[0] else "up")
        print("Move {} to the {}"*(0 if start[1] == finish[1] else 1)).format(abs(start[1]-finish[1]), "right" if start[1] < finish[1] else "left")
```

I apologize for the bounty of code on each line, this was just a quick implementation. You should add error checking and such before submitting this to your instructor.

These functions can be used thusly:

```
>> matrix_str = """---
-m-
--p"""

>> matrix_pathing(matrix_find(matrix_str, 'm'), matrix_find(matrix_str, 'p'))
Move 1 down
Move 1 to the left
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it in this way :

```
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if grid[i][j] == "m":
            mx = i
            my = j
        elif grid[i][j] == "p":
            px = i
            py = j
boolean = True

while boolean:
    if mx > px:
        mx-=1
        print "UP"
    elif mx < px:
        mx+=1
        print "DOWN"
    elif my > py:
        my-=1
        print "LEFT"
    elif my < py:
        my+=1
        print "RIGHT"

    if mx == px and my == py:
        boolean = False
```

Answer (score 0):

As you already solved it by yourself, I just post it for sharing ideas.

Created the matrix as list of lists.
I made several methods, switch values, find path, insert values to certain column and certain row...

```
INIT_VALUE = "-"
COLUMN = 3
ROW = 3


def insert(matrix, num_row, num_col, value):
    """inserts certain value to certain row and column"""
    matrix[num_row][num_col] = value

def find(matrix, value):
    """iterates matrix and find coordinate of target value, return valid
    coordinate if found, return invalid if not"""
    target_row, target_column = 0, 0
    found = False
    for row in matrix:
        if value in row:
            found = True
            target_column = row.index(value)
            break
        target_row += 1

    if found:
        # returns tuple. the order is row number, column number, and value
        return (target_row, target_column, value)
    else:
        return (-1,-1, "x")  # return invalid if not found


def switch(matrix, c1, c2):
    """switch two characters coordinates"""
    matrix[c1[0]][c1[1]] = c2[2]
    matrix[c2[0]][c2[1]] = c1[2] 


def find_path(c1, c2):
    """finds path from coordinate 1 to coordinate 2"""
    row_diff = c1[0] - c2[0]
    column_diff = c1[1] - c2[1]

    row_direction = "Up" if row_diff > 0 else "Down"
    column_direction = "Left" if column_diff > 0  else "Right"

    print "move {} to {}, we need to move {} {} and move {} {}".format(c1[2],c2[2], abs(row_diff), row_direction, abs(column_diff), column_direction)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # initialize matrix
    matrix= [[INIT_VALUE for column in range(COLUMN)] for row in range(ROW)] 

    # insert m
    insert(matrix, 1, 1, "m")
    # insert p
    insert(matrix, 2, 0 , "p")
    print matrix

    m = find(matrix, "m")
    p = find(matrix, "p")

    # try to find a value that does not exist
    unknow = find(matrix, "unknow")
    print m
    print p
    print unknow

    # switches postion of m and p
    switch(matrix, m, p)   
    print matrix

    # finds path from m to p
    find_path(m, p)
```

Run the script and get:

```
hzhang@dell-work ~ $ python test.py 
[['-', '-', '-'], ['-', 'm', '-'], ['p', '-', '-']]
(1, 1, 'm')
(2, 0, 'p')
(-1, -1, 'x')
[['-', '-', '-'], ['-', 'p', '-'], ['m', '-', '-']]
move m to p, we need to move 1 Down and move 1 Left
```